# Ability to change user profile picture to no picture

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, 2016, user-profile-property

We would like to give the end user the ability to decide and have either badge picture or no picture as a profile picture under people search results in SharePoint 2016.

From user profile configuration settings we can just take away the ability to change the profile picture but how to put a functionality in place so that based on user's decision let them choose either to display badge photo or no photo.

Answer (score 1):

- If they do not add a photo to their profile, no photo will show.
- If they add a photo it will show.
- If they remove a previously added photo, no photo will show.

What part of this is not working for you?